# How do I make a class with the following requirements?

Tags: java

Every time I try, it gives me an 'illegal start of type' and 'identifier expected' error.

The class needs to have:
name: Name of character
level: current level of character (default is 1)
XP: current XP of character (default is 0)
maxHP: Maximum total HP of character(default is 20)
HP: Current HP of character(default is maxHP)
gold: current amount of gold(default is 100)
potions: current number of potions(default is 0)

Here's where I don't know what to do. It also needs a constructor for the character name, and a boolean isDead(); that checks to see if HP is above 0 or not. idk how to add those.

Here's my own feeble attempt so far:

```
public class Character {
    System.out.println("Enter your new character's name.");
    System.out.println("\t");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    level = 1;
    XP = 0;
    maxHP = 20;
    HP = maxHP;
    gold = 100;
    potions = 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up "how to declare variable in java"

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: I think you're missing a key conceptual point.  A class isn't a program or a script.

Comment: You should really try a few introductory tutorials on java first.

Comment: Rather than typing random things into a computer and expecting them to work, perhaps a good beginner's book on Java or the Oracle tutorials for the language would be a better route.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must have a `main` method to put your code in. Like this:

```
public class Character
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter your new character's name.");
        System.out.println("\t");
        new Character(input.nextLine());
    }

    public Character(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String name;
    int level = 1;
    int XP = 0;
    int maxHP = 20;
    int HP = maxHP;
    int gold = 100;
    int potions = 0;
}
```

The comments suggested many other improvements, which are here too.

Comment: This will not compile.

Comment: True, because of an extraneous closing brace. I have removed that brace.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for the input though.

Comment: not having a main method is the least of his problems. where are the type declarations, for one thing?

Comment: Another thing. I'll add those to the answer.

Comment: funny how most people post some useless things for a beginner, just to be first or something

Comment: @IAM - `s/funny/sad/p`

Answer (score 1):

I really suggest you to read some [documentation and tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html) for such basic stuff, without understanding this, you won't get far.

- First: to run a program, you need the `public static void main(String[] args) Method` (make your calculations in here)
- See how to [declare variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)
- Constructor is a method of the class, used to construct new objects of this class, it has the same name as your calss:

> ```
> public Charachter(String name){ //pass the name while creating an object
>     this.name=name;
> }
> ```

It mostly makes sense to make it public

- Your boolean method would be:

> ```
> public boolean isDead(){
>     if(this.HP>0) return true;
>     else return false;
> }
> ```

Generally methods have the structure:

1. visibility definition
2. definition of what this method is returning (if nothing, then it's a void, also called procedure)
3. name of the method
4. in the brackets: possible parameters you pass, that will be used for the calculation within the method (not in your case)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the class and its fields along with methods. Here is sample to get you started.

```
public class Character {
    private String name;
    private int level = 1;
    private int xp = 0;
    private int maxHp = 20;
    private int curHp = maxHp;
    private int gold = 100;
    private int potions = 0;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param name
     */
    public Character(String name){
        this.name = name;       
    }

    public boolean isDead(){
        return this.curHp == 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a character that you can create multiples of (what a class is) --

```
public class Character {

    private int level, gold, potions;
    private double xp, maxHP, hp;               // maybe could be ints, not sure

    public Character(String newName) {
        name = newName;
        level = 1;
        xp = 0;
        maxHP = 20;
        hp = maxHP;
        gold = 100;
        potions = 0;            
    }
}
```

Typically you'd want to isolate IO from class creation.

In any case now you can create a new character with `new Character("Robert")`, in a `main` function or whatever context you want to.  You'll have to get the name from the user the same way.